# Building from Eclipse in Windows on a Linux Build Server

Tags: linux, eclipse, build, clearcase, gnu

Setup:
- Eclipse Juno running on Windows 7
- GNU toolchain located on a Linux build server
- ClearCase repository accessible from a Windows 7 machine and a Linux build server

I want to open a C++ project from Eclipse in Windows and be able to build the project on the remote Linux build server. What is the best way to accomplish this now in 2013 with the state of Eclipse development?

(There were some dated questions with partial solutions.)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make a snapshot view directly on a linux path, which is possible through samba: your Windows server would be used for the `view_server.exe`, but the root directory of your snapshot view would be on Linux.

That leaves you with the issue to execute the gnu toolset from Linux from your Windows session. It is discussed in this [2011 thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/63588/#page_top).

> Basically add a new "`Remote Builder`" option for managed build projects.
>   Similar to the `Internal Builder`, but it would invoke the compile commands over SSH or
>   whatever protocol the user chose.

It would be a RMB (Remote Managed Build), as in "[Remote building](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/building-code/remote-build/)".